# How can I rotate the content of a cell without changing the layout of the table

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a UI that requires that I have a table with cells whose text is read vertically instead of horizontally.  To do this, I am using CSS rotate transforms.

The problem I am running into is that the content is being measured before the render transform is taking place.  This is causing my table to render incorrectly, giving wide columns instead of narrow ones.

Is there any way to fix this behavior with either css or javascript?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJCtN/)

Comment: The JSFiddle link should show what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/gJCtN/2/

Also, `vertical-align` is not supported by elements without `display:table-cell` or something like it. [More info](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/).

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/c29rr/

I don't know if it will work in your case since it uses float:left to make the cells behave as divs but it's a start.